# Fixed-top issue using WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

Has anyone experiences this issue with WordPress before? I'm using a Bootstrap 4 Framework with WordPress and would like a fixed-top for the particular project that I'm working on.

The problem is, the fixed-top interferes with WordPress default nav bar an I would like to make adjustments to it without overwriting or messing around with too much BootStrap 4 CSS - Is that possible?

Image:
[image]

As you can see, the menu is not visible due to the default WordPress header. Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body.logged-in .fixed-top{
    top: 32px;
}
```

with a media query to change that margin for the different height on mobile.

Comment: Thanks fo much @mrben522!